# PyCharm & Scoop

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to run some third-party written code in PyCharm, which requires Scoop, so on the command-line you'd write something like `python3 -m scoop foo.py`, which works.

I can't get the `-m scoop` option to be properly passed to the interpreter in PyCharm. I've tried putting `-m scoop` in Interpreter Options, in Script Parameters, `-m` in Interpreter Options and `scoop` in Script Parameters, and all sorts of combinations using double quotes. None seem to work.

In particular, entering `-m scoop` in Interpreter options seems to make PyCharm remove the `-m` part, resulting in a call equivalent to `python3 scoop foo.py`, which obviously doesn't work.

Any ideas how to pass `-m` options to the interpreter in PyCharm?

**Update:** Here's a screenshot showing config and console output.[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should upload images of your configuration in case there's an issue with that.

Comment: Just did so. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the only thing I can say is really different is that I'm running an older version on Windows, and you're running a newer version on Linux.

Comment: Perhaps you should try removing the "Python" > "ltl-fun-gs" config, and try adding `-m scoop` directly to the "Defaults" > "Python" config? IDK.

Answer (score 1):

1. In PyCharm's menu bar, go to "Run" > "Edit Configurations" to open
   the "Run/Debug Configurations" window.
2. Pick the configuration you're running your code with from the list
   on the left side of the window, or make a new one setting everything
   else you need for it.
3. Find the box for "Interpreter Options", and put `-m scoop` in it.

Like so:

[image: PyCharm's "Interpreter options" configuration option, containing "-m scoop".]
(Yes, I'm using Portable Python 2.7. Don't worry, the option will still be in the same place for you.)

This worked for me:

[image: Proof PyCharm added "-m scoop" to my python parameters.]

Comment: Thanks, but like I said this doesn't work for me. In the console it outputs the actual call it makes, and it's missing the `-m` parameter (`scoop` is there). Does it actually work on your machine?

Comment: Yes. See edited answer.
Perhaps you're running it with a different configuration than you're editing?

Comment: Nah, I see the changes happening in the console, except for that missing -m. All other interpreter options work as expected. Does this work in debug mode?

Comment: Dunno then. Might be a bug with this version of PyCharm. Argh :s